# How to access the kendo grid footer template value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, kendo-ui, footer, kendo-grid

i have developed a web application using kendo tools and asp.net mvc4..

below is a screenshot of the grid i'm using and i need to **get the value of footer** under the "Total Stock" column.. according to this, the total value is $74,050.85..

i need to assign this value to a text box or a variable and use it in some where else but there no positive feedback from the online resources..

[image]

can somebody please tell me that **how to get a value from footer template**..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the footer aggregate values (such as total) by setting a [footerTemplate](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid/#configuration-columns.footerTemplate). That footer template can execute arbitrary code such as updating a textbox value.

The other option is to use jQuery to get the text of the footer:

```
var totalText = $("#grid .k-footer-template").text();
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir.. it worked perfectly.. by the way can you please tell me that how can i manually **Set** a value to footer template as well as above line of code can **Get** the value..

Answer (score 4):

i guess you use aggregate function in your kendogrid to calculate Total Stock[so your total $74,050.85..], am i right??

if yes than
this should be the best answer for your question.
example your kendogrid id = 'gridtotal', and your field that aggregated = total_stock

so if you want to get the total, you just do this

```
    var total = $("#gridtotal").data().kendoGrid.dataSource.aggregates().total_stock.sum;
```

here if you want to know more
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-group.aggregates

Comment: I think this is more accurate answer. Because, this will give the raw amount value instead of the formatted footer html.

Answer (score 3):

Under the grid column definition, add

```
footerAttribute: {"id":"total-stock"}
```

This will add an id to the cell. Then you can just use jquery to pull it directly:

```
var totalStock = $("#total-stock").text().split(":")[1]
```

If you wanted to pull the raw numerical value, you could get it as well by parsing the number out, or you can assign it as an attribute to the cell.

```
footerAttribute: {"id":"total-stock", "data-value": sum }
```

Then reference it later

```
var totalStock = $("#total-stock").data("value")
```

Comment: thank you for answering sir.. anyway tell me the way to manually set the value of footer template(total)..

Answer (score 0):

Sanzy,

Have you figured out setting the value of the footer template total?

This is what I used.

```
var totalWeight = 0;
var theGridData = $(gridSelector).data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();
$(theGridData).each(function (index, item) {
    totalWeight += item.Weight;
});
$('#total-stock').text("Total: " + totalWeight);
```

Hope this helps.