# How to read and update the kendo grid footer template value with grid refresh

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, footer

I have a similar problem to what was explained in the following SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144993/how-to-access-the-kendo-grid-footer-template-value).

The problem is only half answered and does not show how to update the footer template if it contains any special template definition.

The Kendo Grid FooterTemplate is defined as follows:

```
<% Html.Kendo().Grid<_3ECProject.Models.TransactionHistoryModel>()
  .Name("creditnoteinfogrid")
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
    columns.Bound(e => e.Amount).Format("{0:#,###.00}")
       .ClientFooterTemplate("<div style='float: right'>#: kendo.toString(sum, '\\#,\\#\\#\\#.00') #</div>")
       .FooterHtmlAttributes(new {id = "total-amount" });
  }
  .Events(events => events.Save("onGridCellSave"))
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax().Batch(true).ServerOperation(false)
    .Aggregates(aggregates =>{
      aggregates.Add(p => p.Amount).Sum();
    })
  )
%>
```

How do I update a footer template with customFooterTemplate() defined.

Using Kendo-MVC - 2020.3.915

Answer (score 0):

One way I found was to replace the footer template DOM element with new innerHTML while keeping the original ClientFooterTemplate() the same.

```
function onGridCellSave(e) {
  e.model.Amount = e.values.Amount;

  var grid = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid');
  var griddata = grid.dataSource.data();
  var totalAmount = 0;
  griddata.forEach(function (item, index) {
    totalAmount = totalAmount + item.Amount;
  });

  console.log(totalAmount);

  //This is the way I update the footer template cell by using the id property and set it with the same HTML set in the .ClientFooterTemplate()
  document.getElementById("total-amount").innerHTML = "<div style='float: right'>" + kendo.toString(totalAmount, '#,###.00') + "</div>";
}
```