# kendoUI- function returns to the calling script in ClientFooterTemplate doesn't match as expected

Tags: kendo-ui

I want in grid footer not only a result of sum of value only i checked in checkbox, but also check all sum value When I click header checkbox - it should've returned '0' or sum(all) .
so I made javascript function with ClientFooterTemplate, and individual counting and displaying result in grid footer works well but check-all sum function doesn't work

[Header Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bp0Lg.png)
[columns bound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLpUk.png)

Below is the JS function in ClientFooterTemplate

function check_sum_ook09(a) {

```
    var result = ''
    var state = ''
 
    if (a == false) {
        var sum = 0
        $('.chkbx').each(function () {
            var grid = $("#grid").data().kendoGrid;
            var dataItem = 
           grid.dataItem($(this).closest('tr'));
            if ($(this).is(":checked") == true) {

                sum += dataItem.OOK_09

            }
        });

        state = 'all off'
        result = sum.toLocaleString('ko-KR');
        console.log(result + ' ' + state)
        return sum.toLocaleString('ko-KR');
       
    
    }
    else {
         var rowIndex = 0;
        var sum_ = 0;
        var grid = $("#grid").data().kendoGrid;
        $.each(grid.dataSource.view(), function () {
            var rows = grid.dataSource.view()[rowIndex];
            sum_ += rows.OOK_09
            rowIndex++;
        });
       
     
        result = sum_.toLocaleString('ko-KR');
        state = 'check all'
        console.log(result + ' ' + state)
        return sum_.toLocaleString('ko-KR');

    }
    
}
```

console.log returns value as i expected
[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohQx6.png)

But in grid footer individual sum return value displayed only.
I don't know reason why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to read and update the kendo grid footer template value with grid refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65600865/how-to-read-and-update-the-kendo-grid-footer-template-value-with-grid-refresh)

ㄴ This Q&A helps a lot.
I solve the problem using innerHTML. I set Id in FooterHtmlAttributes and put sum-values directly in footer of grid.